# selecting qualified records from a group

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables. 1 is the primary table and the other has a 1 to many relationship with the primary table. The table with the many relationship has a field that is being used as a flag. So it usually have a value of Y or null.

So I'd like to select rows from the primary table that has records in the 2nd table only if all the rows on the 2nd table has a Y in its field. In other wards, if the Y field has a null or some other value, they don't qualify.

So the logic is if all rows have a Y than, OK, if some rows have yes and some do not have Y, than they don't qualify in the selection.

Hope that's clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick...

```
SELECT p.Field
FROM PrimaryTable p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SecondaryTable s WHERE p.ID = s.ID AND (s.Flag <> 'Y' OR s.Flag IS NULL))
```

I've assumed that either there will always be a record in SecondaryTable for a given PrimaryTable record....OR, if not, then you still want the primary record returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*
    from primary_table p
        inner join secondary_table s
            on p.join_key = s.join_key
                and s.flag = 'Y'
    where not exists(select null from secondary_table s2 where s2.join_key = p.join_key and (s2.flag is null or s2.flag <> 'Y'))
```

Comment: The question stated that the `flag` can be either `null` or some other value but only values of `Y` can apply. Your statement returns rows from the primary table that can have several values for `flag` in the secondary table, as long as they're not null.

Comment: @Gingi: Thanks. Adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      p.*
   FROM 
      PrimaryTable p,
      ( select s.ID, 
               count(*) AllRecs, 
               sum( case when S.Flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end ) as YesRecCount
           from
               SecondaryTable s
           group by
               s.ID
           having
               AllRecs = YesRecCount ) squalified
   WHERE 
      p.ID = squalified.ID
```